# mocking ajax requests with Backbone on jsfiddle

Tags: backbone.js, jsfiddle

I'm trying to set up a demo of an app I'm making on jsfiddle in order to get help with a problem. It will require making ajax calls. jsFiddle has an echo api (exampel fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/yVbYQ/ ) to mock ajax calls, but I can't figure out how to integrate it within a backbone model or collection, such as I have below. Here's a fiddle of the backbone model...http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/RRXnK/117/ if that assists.

```
var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {

    },
    getStuff: function () {
        var _this = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:realDonaldTrump",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (response) {
               alert(response.results[0]);
                alert("success");
               _this.trigger("gameStartedEvent", response);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert("error");
                alert(r);

            }
        });

    }

});

var game = new Game();
game.getStuff();
```

An example of the jsfiddle mock ajax call

```
new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
    data: {
        tweet1: 'some text',
        tweet2: 'another text'
        tweet3: 'blah blah'
    },
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
}).send();

show_response = function(obj, result) {
    $H(obj).each(function(v, k) {
        new Element('li', {
            text: k + ': ' + v
        }).inject(result);
    });
    result.highlight();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSFiddle echo API doesn't support the range of HTTP operations required to implement Backbone CRUD. With `POST /echo` you can mock create new models, but that's about it.

Instead consider sinon.js [`fakeServer`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer) with the `autoRespond` option to mock your services on the client. This will take some more work, but will provide a more "true" mock.

FWIW, for a normal CRUD use case I would recommend [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage). It's a drop-in replacement for `Backbone.sync`, so just include it as a resource, change your collection's `url` property to `localStorage`, and you're in business. This won't work for you, however, because you're making the AJAX request by hand, so you need to go lower.